# Fiona open OGR_VRT

Tags: python, geospatial, fiona

I have OGR Virtual Format as test.vrt file, and tried to read it using Python `Fiona` lib.

```
>>> import fiona
>>> src = fiona.open('abs_path_to_vrt_file.vrt')
```

After that I am receiving an error:

`fiona.errors.DriverError: unsupported driver: 'OGR_VRT'`

Here is my test.vrt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="test">
        <SrcDataSource>absolute_path_to_test_shp.shp</SrcDataSource>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Fiona only handles a subset GDAL’s supported drivers, and VRT is not one of them:

```
>>> fiona.supported_drivers
{'AeronavFAA': 'r', 'ARCGEN': 'r', 'BNA': 'raw', 'DXF': 'raw', 'OpenFileGDB': 'r', 'ESRI Shapefile': 'raw', 'GeoJSON': 'rw', 'GPKG': 'rw', 'GPX': 'raw', 'GPSTrackMaker': 'raw', 'Idrisi': 'r', 'MapInfo File': 'raw', 'DGN': 'raw', 'PCIDSK': 'r', 'SEGY': 'r', 'SUA': 'r'}
```

VRT files are format drivers - they’re used to create geographic datasets,  reference geographic datasets, and even specify geometric changes to datasets. But VRT files are not geographic datasets themselves. They’re XML files!

Python’s standard library has plenty of support for processing XML files:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html

And there are some great 3rd party options too:

[xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)

[untangle](https://github.com/stchris/untangle)

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough enabling `OGR_VRT` support at least for such simple vrt files seems to be possible. If you add `("OGR_VRT","r")` to supported_drivers dictionary in `site-packages/fiona/drvsupport.py` file opening above xml file with fiona using geopandas seems to work. Use at your own risk! :)